# Spring runs fine on server but not main application

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a new Spring MVC web app project (MVN). I did the whole setup and can "run on server" via Tomcat with Eclipse. The endpoints all work. I can see my jsp pages.

If I however try to run my main application (SpringApplication.run()) on the otherhand- it won't work. I get a 404 on every page.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class,  args);
    }   
}
```

Why is it that if I run this driver class (as opposed to selecting my folder and running it on the server) I am unable to view any pages and only see 404 white label error pages? How do I fix this?

Edit: It seems like my project setup might have been screwy. I assume it might have been from creating a maven project, converting to dynamic web project, and my dependencies. Ended up using Spring.io rather than trying to configure it myself and things work out fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's the package name of your main class and your controllers?

Comment: Thanks! package is com.test and controller is in com.test.controller.

Comment: Note that if you are creating a new application, it is _highly_ advisable to skip "run on server" and external containers entirely; the simplicity of `main` is exactly why the Boot team went to the trouble to write the code for an embedded server.

Comment: I understand. I didn't want to "run on server" which was the way a Udemy course was showing. It's annoying to run/test among other things. Even at my job, we deploy production apps as jars and run them in containers so it didn't make much sense for me to try and learn a way that I'm not doing at work.

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration is ment to run on server (extends SpringBootServletInitializer). Dependent on which project management tool you are using (Maven, Gradle) this configuration should after compilation create WAR file which is supposed to be run on application server (or servlet container, depending on your dependencies).

If you wish to run your spring application from command line remove ServletInitializer and with spring boot tomcat dependency (spring-boot-starter-web already contains it) your application should be compiled to JAR file (again you need to specify this in your project management tool) and should run with embedded tomcat servlet container, thus can be run from command line with java -jar command. Please provide more information (dependencies, and configuration) as its not absolutely clear from your question what you are trying to achieve.

EDIT !
to comment section below
Main class:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ApplicationLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationLauncher.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    public class Root {
        @GetMapping("/")
        public ResponseEntity root() { return ResponseEntity.ok().build(); }
    }
}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent> <!-- main spring boot dependency -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>temp2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- global versions -->
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.resourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>application</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> <!-- plugin to create über WAR file containing all dependencies -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

You can compile with "mvn clean install" then inside target folder you will find your JAR file which can be run from command line.

Comment: I was under the impression that "SpringBootServletInitializer" is needed for web apps. My question is, how do I run Spring as an application and not "run as server" (which would be a deployed WAR)

As mentioned, if I "run as server" then everything works fine. My test pages work. If I try to run it as an application- tomcat starts up but I hit a 404 white label on every page. How do I get it running as an application properly?

Comment: It indeed is but only if you are deploying application to servlet container (or application server which is "superset" of servletcontainer). Since when running as JAR you are deploying to embedded servlet container which behaves differently and doesnt need the servlet context to be initalized. I will edit my answer with minimalistic configuration with Maven project.

Comment: I see. Removing the inheritance however makes no different. I still am hitting 404 white label error pages. 

I'm just so confused and upset. How can it be running 100% fine on server but not when I run the main class with SpringApplication.run()? It makes no sense in my head.

Comment: I'm still unsure what the problem is HOWEVER, using Spring.io should have been my first step and after creating a test build for Spring.io, I can run their test app fine.

I think the issue is within the project properties. I did a maven project then converted it to a dynamic web project. I made sure to use the same deployment assembly configs. It must be how the project was setup. Lesson learned, use Spring.io from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your Pom.xml if it's a maven project.

```
 <groupId>com.spring.demo</groupId>
 <artifactId>springdemo</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Try Removing packaging tag or change War to Jar. so that you can run the project through the main application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem isn't RUNNING as an application. The problem is when it's run as an application- I only ever get 404 white label error pages. It doesn't detect my index.jsp. Nothing. Running it via server on the other hand will display my index and pages just fine.